# Solving an integral with hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus, integration, hypergeometric-function

I have the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{a^{x}}{1+a^{y}+a^{z}}da$$

where parameters $x,y,z$ are constant parameters. My intuition is to solve this integral by the incomplete beta function but I can not see how I can transform the denominator to get a form $\int u(1-u)du$.